# C# windows application error " Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#

I am creating a Windows application form using C# and MSSql Database. There is a form named Discard Item and have two combobox. One for Location and second for Place. I have created a function to get Location in combobox from the database and it is working fine. Now, on `Location_SelectedIndexChanged` event I need to fill Places in combobox with Location ID and for that I have written the code as shown below, but I am receiving an error "Input was not in a correct format" when I run the program.

I have tried `Int32.Parse` method and `Convert.Toint32` method but still getting the error.

```
private void comDiscardLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBconnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetWSPlace", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location_Id", Int32.Parse(comDiscardLocation.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            SqlDataReader rd;
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(rd);

            comDiscardPlace.DataSource = dt;
            comDiscardPlace.ValueMember = "Place_ID";
            comDiscardPlace.DisplayMember = "Place_Name";
            comDiscardPlace.Text = "--------Select--------";
```

Please help me to remove this error.

Comment: This exception is likely occurring on `Int32.Parse(comDiscardLocation.SelectedValue.ToString())`. You need to use your debugger in your IDE and see what the value is at the time this line executes. Learn how to attach your debugger and how to use break points or break on exception. Once you see the value you are trying to parse it should make sense why it can't be converted to an `int` (maybe its empty, null, or clearly not a number).

Comment: A line number for the error would be useful. As @Igor says, it's probably `comDiscardLocation.SelectedValue.ToString()`. What value does that return?

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. You may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).